# How to avoid questions about your/others' sexual orientation in the workplace?

Tags: work-environment

I have no problem with being a little rude about this subject outside work but I can't think of a PC answers if this subject came up for discussion in the office.

Comment: When you say "a little rude" do you mean handling sexually explicit conversation, handling intrusive questioning, handling others being offensive about you, being (deliberately or accidentally) offensive about your colleagues, ...?

Comment: Does it matter? I can be little rude outside work but not at work. Rude as in giving answers like "mind your own business"

Comment: Just clarifying the question, that's all!

Comment: You can be brisk without being rude. For example, just say "No comment." If you look at the person, smile and say this in a friendly tone, you may even be able to emotionally disarm your asker.

Comment: I think a lot depends on the context of the question and how it was asked. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Brandin I would immediately understand that response as "Yes, I'm gay, but shhhh, it's a secret! :-)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say something along the lines of "why? Does it matter?" and leave the ball hanging in their court. I doubt anyone sensible will consider the response to this question as something they can reasonably answer positively. And once they admit it doesn't matter, you've already moved the conversation on, away from this non-constructive subject.

Comment: "Are you hitting on me?" is my typical response, either expressing eagerness or disgust as the circumstances allow. It can quickly end a curious co-worker's prying, and even a manager has to be careful responding further, as they will open themselves up to a discrimination lawsuit.

Answer (score 23):

In a professional setting, asking unprompted about someone's sexual orientation is pretty much always inappropriate. If you don't want to be questioned, then some variation of "it's not an appropriate subject for the office" should suffice. Don't make it about yourself and why *you* don't want to answer; the questioner would be equally wrong asking anyone.

Comment: In my mind, "asking unprompted about someone's sexual orientation" is pretty much always inappropriate, period - even in a private setting. Not everyone wants to share this, and that should be respected.

Answer (score 12):

I agree with Julia Hayward that it's inappropriate to ask at work. I'd suggest a different response, though - "it's not an appropriate subject" may come across as a bit unfriendly.

I'd go with some variation of "Why do you ask?" The response will probably be something along the lines of "Oh, I was just wondering." At that point, you respond only to this last sentence, with e.g. "Oh, OK then" - and then you change the subject. Or you could prolong it a bit with "What made you wonder?" - and whatever they say, you can still respond with "Oh, OK then" and a change of subject.

In other words - turn the question around so that **they** have to explain why they would even ask that question, and then change the subject.

If they persist after this, that's the time to respond with "No, I didn't answer, because I don't think it's an appropriate subject for the office". At that point their insistence is already well past the point of rudeness.

Comment: Seems a little passive-aggressive to me. If the entire subject is inappropriate (and I agree it is) then there is no need to get into any kind of discussion or tactical avoidance mechanism. You can just state that you think it is an inappropriate subject- you don't have to be harsh or rude about it, but stating it sets the correct boundaries IMO

Comment: @MarvMills I believe this is a matter of cultural differences - one person's "clear and straight" is another person's "rude", and one person's "polite" is another person's "passive-agressive" or "weaselly".

Comment: Agreed. But where you are setting boundaries of appropriate behaviour I think that "clear and straight" trumps personal or cultural sensibilities. Someone finding this impolite is far less important than that person knowing where the boundaries are.

Comment: @MarvMills I prefer setting the boundaries in a polite manner, saving the rudeness until the person has stepped over them *after* being politely informed of where they are. YMMV.

Comment: Setting boundaries is *not* intrinsically rude and it is possible to say it in ways that are not rude, as I stated in my first comment. Your proposed course of action actually *fails* to set boundaries by side-stepping the question completely. Personally I feel that is wrong because it puts a higher priority on avoiding upsetting the potential infringer than clearly stating what the boundary actually is. Clearly we have different opinions and that is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Asking people why they want to know is one way of setting the boundary - IMO a polite one. In the workplace, I place a higher value on keeping things on the polite side than I might in my personal life. And yes, this discussion is a splendid example of how people raised in different cultures don't agree on what is polite.

Comment: Asking why may however also lead to an inappropriate response - if it comes across as actual interest in the reason, the other party may (wrongly) feel encouraged to follow up with romantic advances, e.g. "Maybe I'd just want to know if I'm in the candidate pool *wink*" or something like that might follow.

Answer (score 1):

Asking someones sexual orientation is inappropriate in a work context, because it is irrelevant for the job. There is only one industry where asking about someones sexual orientation is work-related, and that is the adult entertainment and sex industry.

And even in that context it should be appropriate to answer questions about your sexual orientation with *"I feel [comfortable|not comfortable] to work with [male|female|transexual] [performers|customers|content]"* without revealing your actual sexual preference you have in a private context.

Answer (score -1):

"I'll give you the short answer: the company hires without regard to sexual orientation. If you can't perform your job without knowing my sexual orientation, then you are working in the wrong place"